# Webpack сборка проекта

Tags: webpack

Есть проект с модулями, которые написаны все на JS.

При подключение этих модулей просто к странице, то ничего не работает. Изначально модули были запакованы webpack (конфига от прошлого webpack нет), т.к. проект собирала другая команда разработчиков. Сейчас сменили разработчика проекта.

Структура папок модулей на скриншоте. Скриншот сделан с панели разработчика Google Chrome. В каждой папке находятся JS файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как собрать и подключить эти модули к проекту, чтобы они заработали?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82764/discussion-on-question-by-alex-webpack--).